# How to bind different child records under different parent rows?

Tags: c#, winforms, foreign-keys, dataset

My requirement is to show the different records of same child table under the different parent records. (For example , if child table has 10 records, the 1st and 3rd will comes under the 1st record of the parent table and 2nd , 4th records comes under the 2nd parent record.) Which relation kind can i use?
Please suggest me your ideas to achieve that? Is it possible?

Thanks in Advance.